# Oracle SQL code syntax standard, Error "not a single-group group function"

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a block of Oracle SQL code that does work. I figured out I cannot get the cert column and the max(run_time) at the same time.

```
select
  cert,
  max(run_time)
from
  bond_films
where title in
(
'Casino Royale','On Her Majesty_s Secret Service','Licence to Kill'
);
```

I was reading a SQL reference and it has the following syntax, but I thought my code matches the syntax?

```
SELECT [column,] group_function(column)
FROM table
[WHERE condition]
[GROUP BY group_by_expression]
[HAVING group_condition]
[ORDER BY column] ;
```

Can someone explain this to me or suggest a source which says I cannot write a code like I did?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause because you have included the `cert` column.  If you had only done `SELECT MAX(run_time)` it would not be necessary to supply a `GROUP BY` since you are selecting the maximum value of all rows.  But, since you have requested another column (`cert`), Oracle expects that you want to retrieve the max value for each different `cert`.

```
select
  cert,
  max(run_time)
from
  bond_films
where title in ('Casino Royale','On Her Majesty_s Secret Service','Licence to Kill')
GROUP BY cert;
```

Comment: Michael, Thank you for your advise. Can you tell me where to find relevent syntax so that I know I have to use GROUP BY in this case?

Comment: @Dean I'm sorry I can't find the relevant Oracle docs, and I only know it from experience.  MySQL will not require `GROUP BY` in this instance and would group & return all rows, but Oracle & others require it.